# Maven m2eclipse detect changes in dependecy in workspace and automatically install

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

I found an annoying issue working with m2eclipse in Eclipse.

My workspace contains 2 projects, an application A and a library B. The application A POM has B as a dependency and everything works correctly. (The project dependecy is found and used when I build the application)

But if I change some code in project B and I forgot to mvn:install it, when I build the application  it uses the last built version of the library and it loses my last changes.

Is there a way to force Maven / M2Eclipse to check if the source code  of the dependecy is newer than the last version built, and to install it when installing/ deploying the main application?

Or maybe my approach is wrong or is something obvious that I'm missing?

Comment: Can you explain a little more about your process. Are you talking about building and deploying your application from your local machine? Are you running it on your local machine? Are you talking about deploying snapshots or releases?

Comment: Yes, I'm talking about deploying snapshot versions locally.

Answer (score 2):

You can tell m2eclipse to use resolve dependencies from the workspace rather than through the normal mechanisms. In your project properties (NOT workspace properties), select Maven->Resolve dependencies from Workspace projects.

[image: Project properties Maven -> Resolve dependencies from Workspace projects]

This will mean that when you change B and subsequently build A, the changes should be picked up automatically.

If, however, you build outside Eclipse, you'll have to do the normal mvn install to get the correct dependencies.

Comment: I have that check enabled in both projects, but the changes are not picked up. But my properties dialog is much simpler than yours. ¿Maybe because I'm using an Eclipse(STS)-embedded Maven?

Comment: This is m2eclipse version 0.9.8.200905041414 on Eclipse Galileo. Yours may be slightly different, but the same rules apply. What do you have in your Project->Java Build Path, Libraries tab. Does this have the workspace version of the dependency or the repository version? If the latter, try to update Project->Maven->Update dependencies. One other thing to try is in the Java Build Path, Order and Export path, try checking the box with Maven dependencies.

Comment: Make sure dependency version in Eclipse workspace matches version in your project pom.xml and also make sure you are not referencing jars from the local Maven repository directly. You can simply fix project configuration by invoking Maven / Uppdate Project Configuration action from popup menu on your project.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a way to tell maven to build the library first, then build your project. You could put two maven commands into a script and run the script.

Alternatively, you could put both projects inside a maven parent project, and then build the parent. This causes all child project to be built too (so in your case the library, and the application).

Comment: I thought before about a parent project, but I would like my B library project to be as independent as posible, because it is a standard library and multimodule-projects (parent POMs) force me to modify child POMs and to use fixed paths for projects code. Am I wrong? It is not really a module of the application, is a library it uses

Comment: Yeah, you can't really do what you want right now with maven. What you want is some kind of "sibling project" setup, where maven knows that although the projects are separate, you're in charge of both and it should do a build of the library when you build the app.

I have a similar setup, and I do it via a bash script that just builds the library first, the app second.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have couple of options here

1. If you can change the maven project set up, I would suggest you to use maven [multimodule](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnex-book/reference/multimodule.html)
2. Option two might solve your problem but still involves a manual stop when you change your dependent project B, Do this on for your dependent project in eclipse
3. Select Library B ==> Properties ==> Maven ==> in the input box under Goals to invoke after project clean: ==> enter : install
4. To deploy any change that you made to Project B in eclipse to maven local/remote repo, You have to run Clean build in eclipse, This will deploy the latest Library B to the maven repository
5. Also make sure your Library B version is a SnapShot during the development

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to run the latest snapshots on your local machine you should try to set things up to launch directly from Eclipse.

Apart from avoiding the problem you originally posted about, it also has other advantages.

- It will save you a lot of time by not having to perform intermediate build steps.
- You can start and stop servers without having to leave your IDE.
- The Eclipse console has extra features that you don't get from the system console.
- You don't have to modify your start scripts to attach a debugger.

Comment: Yes, I try to launch directly from the IDE everytime I can, but in this case it is  much more complex: What I call my application is a Liferay portlet, bundled as a WAR, which gets autodeployed to a local running Liferay Tomcat Server. The deploy job is done via a Maven plugin.
Anyway, I could investigate further  how to launch Liferay directly from the IDE, this could be a great solution. But it doesn't seem easy at all.

Comment: A really confusing answer. The m2eclipse dependency resolver allows to pickup code from dependent projects automatically, assuming pom references a correct version of dependencies in Eclipse workspace.

Comment: @Eugene Sorry if it confused you. I think Juan knew what I was talking about. Maybe you don't understand what Juan is asking. Your comment won't solve his problem because he is not running from within Eclipse.